# Strange delay in jQuery animation in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-8, jquery-animate, internet-explorer-10

I am building a windows8 app using JavaScript.

I have the following methods:

```
var openBag = function () {

    logTime('inside openBag');

    $('#bag').stop().animate({
        right: 0
    }, {
        duration: 400,
        complete: function(){
            logTime('after openBag');
        }
    });
};


var logTime = function(str) {
    console.log((new Date()).getSeconds(), str);
}
```

Here is the output I got in the latest run:

```
9,inside openBag
16,after openBag
```

Why is there a 7 second delay before the animation? The animation itself takes only 400 milliseconds  as expected, and the animation is smooth. But, the delay is before the animation start.

The delay varies between tests, and I have no clue what might be causing the issue.

Comment: Doesn't happen on Windows 7 running IE10 for anyone trying this.

Comment: This happens in win8 app. Don't know if they have fixed this.

Comment: Yeah, I just thought I'd point that out to anybody else trying to help. Have you tried the IE10 Metro browser to see if the problem exists there too?

Comment: No. I did not. I tested the code only inside the App. Probably they have fixed this by now. I haven't checked in a while